# How to create DAM Taxonomy in CQ5

Tags: aem, dam

I am working on CQ 5.6.1 for a while but i didn't have much knowledge on DAM. So was studying DAM. I came across a term DAM Taxonomy. I couldn't see any direct link to it in documentation.

I want to know what is DAM Taxonomy and how can we create DAM Taxonomy in CQ 5.6.1?

Can we create these taxonomies in CQ 5 or we should use third party applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomy in DAM is no different from the one we have for Sites. You could access it directly in http://localhost:4502/tagging.

Giving you a brief on tagging - Tags are a greater way to organize content / assets. Tags are critical for search. Defining and managing tags are essential as it impacts the search which is the #1 use-case in most DAM deployments.

Links:

DAM & tagging - http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/dam_documentation.html#Using%20Tags%20to%20Organize%20Assets

Tagging - http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/content/tags.html